# What is the command to open a file in specified ViewColumn in VS Codium?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks

How can I open a specific file in a specified split view with an built-in command in VS codium? Is that possible without writing an extension?

I have a project, and I periodically I want to open a pair of files in specific way in split view. Let's mention them as `problem1.py` and `problem1.txt`. I want to programmatically open problem1.py in the left side, and the problem1.txt in the right side.

I found an a documentation for the command [`vscode.open`](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/commands#:%7E:text=opens%20the%20provided%20resource%20in%20the%20editor):

> vscode.open - Opens the provided resource in the editor. Can be a text or binary file, or an http(s) URL. If you need more control over the options for opening a text file, use vscode.window.showTextDocument instead.
>
> - uri - Uri of a text document
> - columnOrOptions - (optional) Either the column in which to open or editor options, see vscode.TextDocumentShowOptions
> - label - (optional)
> - (returns) - no result

In `keybindings.json` I created following statements:

```json
    {
        "key": "numpad4",
        "command": "vscode.open",
        "args": "/home/user/myproject/README.md"
    },
    {
        "key": "numpad6",
        "command": "vscode.open",
        "args": ["/home/user/myproject/README.md", "1"]
    },
```

Now when I press `numpad4`, it works perfectly, the readme file opens. But when I press `numpad6`, I get a notification:

> Unable to open '': An unknown error occurred. Please consult the log for more details.

Am I passing parameters in a wrong way? Why it does not detect a filename? And I do not see whare to view a log.

---

Additional info:

VS codium version: 1.66.2.

I saw a cli option `-r, --reuse-window`, but it has not control of in which view I want to open a file.

I saw a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56902750/how-to-open-file-into-vs-code-split-window-programatically/56903963#56903963), but there the author wants to do it from extension, while I would prefer to not write an extension for this problem. Also, as documentation says, I think I do not need vscode.window.showTextDocument, as vscode.open should be enough for my task.

Here is an enum list for available ViewColumn values: https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#ViewColumn

Comment: you can use the extension [HTML Related Links](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.html-related-links#open-a-file) use command `htmlRelatedLinks.openFile`

Comment: Looks like exactly what I needed. I see you are an author of that extension. Still interested why that extension is needed. Can you please make a proper answer so I can upvote? Also, why does it ignore "viewColumn": "1" and "viewColumn": "2"? It always opens document in a current view.

Comment: don't give it a string value but a numeric value: `"viewColumn": 1`, maybe have to adjust the README to make it clear

Comment: I think the `vscode.open` command was not really intended for use outside an extension.  Note that the first argument is a `uri` which you wouldn't normally have easy access to except in an extension.  [That was later relaxed to a simple path string, but the documentation was never updated.]  This is why there are a number of extensions to do this, but `HTML Related Links` appears to handle the viewColumn arg whereas some others don't.

Comment: Thanks, replacing string to numeric value (deleting quotes) worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the extension [HTML Related Links](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.html-related-links#open-a-file) use command `htmlRelatedLinks.openFile`

```
  {
    "key": "numpad6",
    "command": "htmlRelatedLinks.openFile",
    "args": {
      "file": "${workspaceFolder}/README.md",
      "method": "vscode.open",
      "viewColumn": 1
    }
  }
```

Comment: Can you please also look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72149886/is-it-possible-to-use-input-variables-in-keybindings-in-vs-codium?

Answer (score 0):

Combining the @rioV8's solution of using [HTML Related Links](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.html-related-links#open-a-file) and @Mark's solution for [combining two commands](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49612562/7869636) into one, the resulting `keybindings.json` is the following:

```json
    {
        "key": "numpad5",
        "command": "extension.multiCommand.execute",
        "args": {
            "sequence": [
                {   "command": "htmlRelatedLinks.openFile",
                    "args": {
                        "file": "/home/user/myproject/problem1.py",
                        "method": "vscode.open",
                        "viewColumn": 1,
                    }
                },
                {   "command": "htmlRelatedLinks.openFile",
                    "args": {
                        "file": "/home/user/myproject/problem1.txt",
                        "method": "vscode.open",
                        "viewColumn": 2,
                    }
                },
            ]
        }
    },
```