# Prevent asynchronous order of command sequence execution in VS Codium

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks

How can I control the execution order of [multiCommand](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ryuta46.multi-command) extension? It behaves like it executes them in parallel, while I want them to be executed one after another.

I have a project with the following structure:

```
/home/user/myproject/dir1/problem1.py
/home/user/myproject/dir1/problem1.txt
/home/user/myproject/dir1/problem2.py
/home/user/myproject/dir1/problem2.txt
...
/home/user/myproject/pointer.txt
```

The `pointer.txt` contains the text: `dir1/problem2`.

I want to press a shortcut, and do a sequence of actions:

- Create next problem files pair
- Modify a pointer.txt to point to new files
- Open them in the editor

I setuped the following things.

In `settings.json` I defined the command sequence named "openPointedProblemLayout" (for being able to easily [reuse it](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ryuta46.multi-command#:%7E:text=usage%20with%20settings.json)):

```json
"multiCommand.commands": [
        {
            "command": "multiCommand.openPointedProblemLayout",
            "sequence": [
                {   "command": "htmlRelatedLinks.openFile",
                    "args": {
                        "file": "${command:mypointer}.py",
                        "method": "vscode.open",
                        "viewColumn": 1,
                        "command": {
                            "mypointer": {
                                "command": "extension.commandvariable.file.content",
                                "args": {
                                    "fileName": "${workspaceFolder}/pointer.txt"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                {   "command": "htmlRelatedLinks.openFile",
                    "args": {
                        "file": "${command:mypointer}.txt",
                        "method": "vscode.open",
                        "viewColumn": 2,
                        "command": {
                            "mypointer": {
                                "command": "extension.commandvariable.file.content",
                                "args": {
                                    "fileName": "${workspaceFolder}/pointer.txt"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
            ]
    
        },
    ]
```

In `tasks.json` I created a shell command definition, that creates a new .py and .txt pair and also changes the pointer:

```json
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "create_new_problem_files_pair",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "python /home/user/scripts/create_new_problem_files_pair.py \"${file}\""
        },
    ],
}
```

In `keybindings.json` I defined shortcut numpad2 that executes both actions (creates files and opens them) and a numpad5 (just opens them):

```json
    {
        "key": "numpad2",
        "command": "extension.multiCommand.execute",
        "args": {
            "sequence": [
                {
                    "command": "workbench.action.tasks.runTask",
                    "args": "create_new_problem_files_pair"
                },
                {
                    "command": "multiCommand.openPointedProblemLayout"
                },
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "key": "numpad5",
        "command": "extension.multiCommand.execute",
        "args": { "command": "multiCommand.openPointedProblemLayout" },
    },
```

Now, when I press numpad2, the two new files are created:

```
/home/user/myproject/dir1/problem3.py
/home/user/myproject/dir1/problem3.txt
```

And then two files *are* opened in layout (means the command actually runs), **but wrong files**. They are problem2.py and problem2.txt, i.e. the **previous** pointer is used.

I checked the content of the pointer.txt now, and it actually contains `dir1/problem3`. And when I press numpad5, they are opened correctly.

Why does the VS Codium uses previous content of pointer, while **at the moment of command run, it should already take the new content?** It looks like VS Code executes the command sequence in parallel, instead of sequence them.

Am I doing something wrong? Is that an issue with configuration or vs code itself or maybe in multiCommand extension?

Comment: You could try using the `interval` property of multi-command and see if it helps.

Comment: I did (added `"interval": 500,`), and it does not help unfortunately.

Comment: I also added this question in the multiCommand project: https://github.com/ryuta46/vscode-multi-command/issues/54

Comment: how large do you have to set the interval before it works, maybe the task starting is executed but not the full task end is waited for

Comment: I see the documentation says the units are milliseconds. I wanted to set it to 5000 (5 sec). But currently I got a problem. I updated vscodium to 1.67.0, and it stopped working normally. When I press a shortcut, it says `command 'extension.multiCommand.execute' not found`, while the multiCommand extension is installed. Tried to downgrade to 1.66.2, and the problem persists. I am stuck now.

Comment: Also, when opening a py file, I get the message `
Cannot activate the 'Pylance' extension because it depends on the 'Python' extension, which is not loaded. Would you like to reload the window to load the extension?`

Comment: Have they "fixed" the use of MarketPlace extensions in VSCodium

Comment: No. It seems that multiCommand extension is broken. Strange how it is possible, because it did not updated recently. But I did lots of experiments, installing different versions of code-oss, codium and even ms-vs-code-bin, and the result is the same. In this https://dae.me/blog/2603/vs-code-bind-one-key-to-multiple-commands-without-an-extension/ article I found an alternative extension called macros. It at least launches. I would even prefer to keep all this in tasks.json, to make it in project scope. But I did not found a way how to pass arguments to the commands in such case.

Comment: Using [macros](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=geddski.macros) extension leads to the same result. The layout is opened, but it tries to open previous pointed files. And I do not see any thing like "interval" in macros. Any advice?

Comment: Looks like that is also a known issue in macros extension. Found this pr https://github.com/geddski/macros/pull/11, but it did not worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

I have solved the problem by avoiding usage of any extensions. A command sequence can be defined via Tasks. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/72201981/7869636

In `keybindings.json` I define:

```json
    {
        "key": "numpad2",
        "command": "workbench.action.tasks.runTask",
        "args": "create_new_problem_files_pair_and_open_file_pair_in_layout"
    },
```

And in `tasks.json` I defined the whole things:

```json
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "create_new_problem_files_pair",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "python /home/user/scripts/create_new_problem_files_pair.py \"${file}\""
        },
        {
            "label": "open_file_pair_in_layout",
            "dependsOrder": "sequence",
            "dependsOn": [
                "open_in_layout_left",
                "open_in_layout_right",
            ],
        },
        {
            "label": "create_new_problem_files_pair_and_open_file_pair_in_layout",
            "dependsOrder": "sequence",
            "dependsOn": [
                "create_new_problem_files_pair",
                "open_file_pair_in_layout",
            ],
        },
        {
            "label": "open_in_layout_left",
            "command": "${input:open_in_layout_left}",
        },
        {
            "label": "open_in_layout_right",
            "command": "${input:open_in_layout_right}",
        },
    ],
    "inputs": [
        {
            "id": "open_in_layout_left",
            "type": "command",
            "command": "htmlRelatedLinks.openFile",
            "args": {
                "file": "${command:mypointer}.py",
                "method": "vscode.open",
                "viewColumn": 1,
                "command": {
                    "mypointer": {
                        "command": "extension.commandvariable.file.content",
                        "args": {
                            "fileName": "${workspaceFolder}/pointer.txt"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "id": "open_in_layout_right",
            "type": "command",
            "command": "htmlRelatedLinks.openFile",
            "args": {
                "file": "${command:mypointer}.txt",
                "method": "vscode.open",
                "viewColumn": 2,
                "command": {
                    "mypointer": {
                        "command": "extension.commandvariable.file.content",
                        "args": {
                            "fileName": "${workspaceFolder}/pointer.txt"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

This approach has a benefit that it defines these tasks in a scope of that project's workspace, and not globally in `setting.json`.