# vscode variables expansion in keybindings.json or in tasks.json/inputs

Tags: vscode-extensions

In light of this answer
https://stackoverflow.com/a/72150541/4335781

with the extension [Command Variable](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.command-variable#commands)

is it possible to get any vscode variable to be expanded in the  keybindings.json or in tasks.json/inputs?

using v1.49.1 of Command Variable extension

for example:

```
{
        "key": "ctrl+'",
        "command": "workbench.action.findInFiles",
        "args": {
            "query": "whatever",
            "replace": "",
            "isRegex": true
            "filesToInclude": "${command:mypointer}",
            "command": {
                "mypointer": {
                  "command": "extension.commandvariable.file.filePosix"
                }
            }
        }
    },
```

the `"${command:mypointer}"` is not expanded to the currently open file none of `extension.commandvariable` are expanded in the keybinding.json

I tried also to create a task and  get the built in command in `inputs` using the same extension.
for example:

```
 "tasks": [     
       {
            "label": "my_task",
            "command": "${input:call_built_in_function}",
            "problemMatcher": []

        }
    ],
    "inputs": [
        {
            "id": "fname",
            "type": "command",
            "command": "extension.commandvariable.file.filePosix"
        }
        ,
        {
            // using inputs, I can pass the arguments of the build in command
          "id": "call_built_in_function",
          "type": "command",
          "command": "workbench.action.findInFiles",
          "args": {
            "query": "whatever",
            "replace": "",
            "isRegex": true,
            "filesToInclude": "${input:fname}",
            // I expected here that the opended editor file name will be used
            // However it is not expanded.

            //"filesToInclude": "${extension.commandvariable.file.filePosix}",
            // this one also does not work
            // "filesToInclude":"${command:extension.commandvariable.file.filePosix}"
           // does not work neither
            }
        },

      ]
```

attached photo shows the output of using either the keymap shortcut or running the task

[vscode output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sXyVG.png)

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer:

```
{
"version": "0.2.0",
"tasks": [
    {
        "label": "echo top 2 workspace folder names",
        "command": "${input:mycommand}"
    }
],
"inputs": [
    {
        "id": "mycommand",
        "type": "command",
        "command": "extension.commandvariable.transform",
        "args": {
            "text": "${command:findInFiles}",
            "command": {
                "findInFiles": {
                    "command": "workbench.action.findInFiles",
                    "variableSubstArgs": true,
                    "args": {
                        "query": "[\\xa0]",
                        "replace": "",
                        "isRegex": true,
                        "filesToInclude": "${file}"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
]
}
```

thanks to response from [rioj7](https://github.com/rioj7/command-variable/issues/57)